# Best Regex regular expression to match a list of command delimited FQDN's

Tags: regex, fqdn

Can someone help me write a regular expression to verify a list of FQDN's (fully qualified domain names).  The possibilities are:

- [No entry] - Although I can verify this by checking the field is
  empty
- [one entry] - example:

  ```
  webtest.se1.server.net
  ```
- [more than one entry, separated by a comma] - example:

  ```
  webtest.se1.server.net, webtest.se2.server.net
  ```
- Can be in upper or lower case.
- Cannot start with a comma - for example:

  ```
  , webtest.se1.server.net
  ```
- cannot be separated by spaces, for example:

  ```
  webtest.se1.server.net webtest.se2.server.net
  ```
- can have a space after the comma or not, for example:

  ```
  webtest.se1.server.net, webtest.se2.server.net,webtest.se3.server.net
  ```

Comment: Why not just split the string using the comma? Then do a lookup to check each one in turn

Comment: So I don't need to extract any part of the strings.  I just need to verify that the entire sting is in a valid format.

Comment: Just divide the string into a series of strings using the comma. Test each of those strings

Answer (score 0):

Something like: `^([0-9a-zA-Z\-_.]+(,|, ){0,1})*$`

Explanation:

- `^` is the beginning of the string anchor
- `$` is the end of the string anchor
- `[...]` is a character class definition
- `\*` is "zero-or-more" repetition

Comment: This almost works.  I need to add a '-' for addresses such as abc-def.  However it accepts a space as a delimiter, how can I adjust it so it wont accept: abc.com def.com?

^([0-9a-zA-Z.-]+[,| ,]*)*$

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+(, ?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+)*$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/tFc9unAiUz) (working with your examples).